# How to serialize ZF2 form object to JSON?

Tags: ajax, json, forms, zend-framework2

I'm using zf2 form object on the server and ajax code on the client to implement my registration form.
I post the form values in the ajax request, no problem, and the form gets them fine with

```
$form->setData($request->getPost());
```

After I validate the form and perform the registration on the server, I want to send the form back to the client, especially if there are errors, so I can show them to the user.
I'm looking for a standard way using zend or any plugin to serialise the form object into JSON format, so I can send it in the response to the AJAX call.
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well what you can do is run the validation on your form and after that you will return your form within a `new JsonModel`.

Here is a little example of how to handle your controller:

```
class RegistrationController extends AbstractActionController 
{
    public function RegisterAction()
    {
        $form = new RegisterForm();
        $form->setInputFilter(new RegisterInputFilter());

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $form->setData($this->getRequest()->getPost());

            if($form->isValid()) {
                // Handle your registration as the form is valid!
                // return to some path after registration is complete.
                // Show user he registered succesfully, etc. ;)
            }
            // Checks if the request is from JavaScript
            if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                return new JsonModel(array('registerForm' => $form));
            }
        }
        return new ViewModel(array('registerForm' => $form));
    }
}
```

Notice that the form object is holding all the invalid inputs including its message after validation.

I would take another approach just to completely render the `ViewModel` again so you can display the validation message much easier. *On the side you could add Client Side (Javascript) validation as it's much more user-friendly, but that is just some fancy shizzle I would do ;)* In case of rendering the `ViewModel`:

```
use Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer;

if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    $renderer = new PhpRenderer;
    $registerViewModel = new ViewMOdel();
    $registerViewModel->setTemplate('view/register.phtml');
    return new JsonModel(array('registerViewModel' => $renderer->render($registerViewModel));
}
```

Note that not setting a template to your `viewModel` will result in ZF2 getting the default  of the action (`view/moduleName/registration/register.phtml`) you are in! So in your case you don't need to use `PhpRenderrer::setTemplate()`. But I just hand it to you so you can change it if you are using any other file.

So now you will receive `Json` from our controller, in your javascript. Retrieve the new `ViewModel` from `Json` and remove the old `ViewModel` and **replace** it with the new. By removing the old, you also remove any Javascript that is bound to any element within the `viewModel`, so you might set the events on your body within your javascript or have it on your attributes in `Form/RegistrationForm`.

Hope this pushes you in the right direction.